# Create PopOver Without Arrows and Centered in UIViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, size, uipopovercontroller

I am attempting to display a PopOver in the Center of the ipad in Landscape Orientation. I am able to do it now with the code below but it does not have the Properties that are associated with the "popOverViewController" that is linked up on storyboard. I want it to be a view on storyboard so that I am able to work on and edit it. As well as be able to change the size of it to be either 50% or 75% of the ipads full view and no arrow...

Please, anything will help. *Updated code....can now set size. But still not seeing the "popOverViewController" content.

```
self.popOverViewController = [[PopOverViewController alloc]init];
self.popOver = [[UIPopoverController alloc]
                            initWithContentViewController:self.popOverViewController];
CGSize size = CGSizeMake(400.0,300.0);
[self.popOver setPopoverContentSize:size];
CGRect rect = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width/2, self.view.frame.size.height/2, 1, 1);
[self.popOver presentPopoverFromRect:rect inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:0 animated:YES];
```

Comment: is your popOverViewController properly linked as the file owner of your popOver view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright. So I did this...

```
popOverViewController =  [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"popOver"];
```

Answer (score 1):

Just copy & Paste the below code

```
UIViewController *popovercontroller=[[UIViewController alloc] init];
UIView *popoverView=[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(312,390, 400, 344)];
popoverView.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];

popovercontroller.contentSizeForViewInPopover=CGSizeMake(400, 300);



UIDatePicker *pickerView = [[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 44, 400, 0)];
[pickerView setTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
[pickerView addTarget:self action:@selector(dueDateChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

pickerView.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDate;
pickerView.hidden = NO;
NSString *bs ; //= [NSString alloc];
//    //NSDate *newDate = [NSData alloc];
bs =  CurrentSelectedDate;
if (bs.length >= 1) {
    NSDateFormatter* dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] ;
    //        //[dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterLongStyle];
    //        [dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterNoStyle];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MMM-yyyy"];
    // NSDate *myDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString: txtText.text];
    pickerView.date = [dateFormatter dateFromString: CurrentSelectedDate];

}
else
{
    pickerView.date = [NSDate date];
}
[popoverView addSubview:pickerView];



// pickerView.date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:txtText.text];
UIToolbar *pickerToolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 400, 44)];
pickerToolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleDefault;
pickerToolbar.barTintColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:150.0f/255.0f green:91.0f/255.0f blue:129.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f];

[pickerToolbar sizeToFit];
self.navigationController.toolbar.barTintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:150.0f/255.0f green:91.0f/255.0f blue:129.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f];
NSMutableArray *barItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

UIBarButtonItem *flexSpace = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFixedSpace target:self action:nil];
[barItems addObject:flexSpace];

UIBarButtonItem *doneBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(doneButtonPressed:)];
doneBtn.tintColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
[barItems addObject:doneBtn];

UIBarButtonItem *cancelBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel target:self action:@selector(cancelButtonPressed:)];
 cancelBtn.tintColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
[barItems addObject:cancelBtn];

[pickerToolbar setItems:barItems animated:YES];


[popoverView addSubview:pickerToolbar];
popovercontroller.view=popoverView;

pickerViewPopup = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:popovercontroller];

[pickerViewPopup presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(312, 212, 400, 344) inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:0 animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason you can't see any content is because by explicitly recreating a view controller from scratch that you already have hooked up to an outlet, the compiler assumes you'd like to trash the old value and releases the view controller instance IB created.  Or, if this is a separate storyboard or XIB, then the proper initializer would be `-initWithNibName:bundle:`.  Just omit/edit the first line, and assuming the outlets are hooked up correctly, you should see what you've put up in IB.

Comment: That makes sense. However, I only alloc and init it there because before it was nil and would crash the program. I am currently trying to initWithNIbName, but I am unsure of how to set the nib Name of the ViewController on IB.

Comment: @DTDev How is it nil if you said you'd hooked the outlet up?

Comment: Okay. I think I'm starting to understand...or maybe I'm further from understanding.
So I have, in IB, the View Controller I want displayed in the PopOver. The Main VC has PopOverViewController in the .h file as a VC custom class. The Main view also has the UIPopOverController in the .h file.

Should the UIP.O.Controller be in the Custom VC class for PopOverViewController.?

Comment: Secondly. I don't have the PopOverViewController linked up by a way of button but more a method. The only way I know it is "linked up" is that the "Custom Class" field in IB does have the custom class referenced.

Answer (score 0):

I've just been working this one out but wanted to do as much in the storyboard as possible which changes the approach a bit:

1) Select the popover in the storyboard and un-tick Directions Up/Down/Left/Right to get rid of the arrows.

To center it on screen override prepare for segue and do something like this:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    UIStoryboardPopoverSegue* popover = (UIStoryboardPopoverSegue*)segue;
    CGFloat horizontalInset = (self.view.frame.size.width - popover.popoverController.popoverContentSize.width) / (CGFloat)2.0;
    CGFloat verticalInset = (self.view.frame.size.height - popover.popoverController.popoverContentSize.height) / (CGFloat)2.0;
    popover.popoverController.popoverLayoutMargins =
        UIEdgeInsetsMake(
            verticalInset,
          horizontalInset,
            verticalInset,
          horizontalInset);
}
```

In my case I also found that the popover segue's corner radius didn't match my design so I change the background color to clear to sort that out i.e. add this to the above block:

```
popover.popoverController.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

2) In the destination controller for the segue find the attribute 'Popover' and tick 'Use Explicit Size' and put the size of you want it to appear in popover mode.

Answer (score 0):

Making the background color clear almost worked for me but it messed up the grayed out background. The the part of the view that was directly behind the arrow was clear and the rest of the background way gray. So I changed the color to whatever the grayed out alpha was.

```
 UIPopoverController *popoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:newViewController];

 popoverController.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:0.15];
```